# Set plotly bargap to 0

Tags: python, plotly

I am unable to set the plotly bargap to 0 (am using datetime for x axis)

here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly
print (plotly.__version__)
# Create a list of dates for the first day of each month in a year

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "month": pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2022-08-01', freq='MS'),
    "count":  np.random.randint(0, 11, size=20)

})

import plotly.express as px 

fig = px.bar(df, x='month', y='count')
fig.update_layout(width=1200, height=400, bargap=0)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="M1",
    tickformat="%b\n%Y")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `month` column from date to object type:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly
import plotly.express as px 


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "month": pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2022-08-01', freq='MS'),
    "count":  np.random.randint(0, 11, size=20)

})

df.month = df.month.dt.strftime('%b-%Y')

fig = px.bar(df, x='month', y='count')

fig.update_layout(bargap=0)
fig.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]